# Databricks is treating NULL as string

Tags: databricks, delta-lake

I am using Databricks Unity Catalog, and I have a requirement to upload a CSV file, process it, and load it into a final table. However, when uploading the file in Databricks, it converts NULL data to the string 'NULL', which is causing an issue. Do you have any ideas on how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: When I am uploading a csv file databricks is treating Null values as 'NULL' Strings which is causing issue. Lets say this is a date field and I need to convert it then it is failing because of 'NULL' string.

Comment: ok.where you are using databricks. azure,aws or community?

Comment: I am using aws databricks

Answer (score 1):

CSV files by definition doesn't have any way to specify `null` values - everything is treated as a string.  If you have some placeholder value inside your CSV, then you can pass the `nullValue` parameter when reading the CSV data to specify what strings would be treated as nulls (see [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv)):

```py
df = spark.read.csv(path, nullValue="null")
```

or specify it as option:

```py
df = spark.read.format("csv") \
  .option("nullValue", "null")
  .load(path)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex, but I am uploading the data and creating a delta table out of it. I am not directly reading from the file.